# Converge origins on destination leaflet geodesic

Tags: leaflet, geodesic, tabletop-js

I am using Tabletop.js to map locations on a leaflet map.  With each row I add the lat lng to a feature group and then to the map. What I would also like to do is use [leaflet geodesic](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic) to draw a line between *all* latlng pair (origins) and a single destination (orleans). Instead what I get is a line drawn between the last origin and orleans.

Here is what I have tried...

```
    var Geodesic = L.geodesic([], {
        weight:3,
        opacity:1,
        steps: 50
    }).addTo(map);

    var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
    var orleans = new L.LatLng(30.053206, -89.934873);
    var origin;
    Tabletop.init({
        key: code,
        callback: function (sheet, tabletop) {
            for (var i in sheet) {
                var place = sheet[i];
                marker = L.marker([place.lat, place.lon])
                    .addTo(fg)
                    .bindPopup(place.Name)
                origin = new L.LatLng(place.lat, place.lon);
                Geodesic.setLatLngs([[origin, orleans]]);
            }
        },
        simpleSheet: true
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply instantiate your `L.Geodesic`s **inside** the `for (var i in sheet)` loop, like

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var orleans = new L.LatLng(30.053206, -89.934873);
var origin;
Tabletop.init({
    key: code,
    callback: function (sheet, tabletop) {
        for (var i in sheet) {
            var place = sheet[i];
            marker = L.marker([place.lat, place.lon])
                .addTo(fg)
                .bindPopup(place.Name)
            origin = L.latLng(place.lat, place.lon);

            var geodesic = L.geodesic([[origin, orleans]], {
                weight:3,
                opacity:1,
                steps: 50
            }).addTo(fg).addTo(map);

        }
    },
    simpleSheet: true
})
```

Comment: This is failing silently?  https://jsfiddle.net/remmi11/dfro5dve/3/

Comment: Apparently Leaflet.Geodesic needs to be passed an array of arrays of latlngs (i.e. `L.geodesic([[origin, orleans]] ,...`. See https://jsfiddle.net/whyqnucf/

Comment: Thanks! @IvanSanchez This is working perfectly.  If you can revise your answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: Hm, if I may comment, my answer below suggests just this solution, and it was published before Ivan's answer.

Comment: While I'm sure your answer is fundamentally correct @TomazicM, more detail was provided by Ivan to help me implement.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `Leflet.Geodesic` plugin, but from documentation on plugin home page https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic it looks like that if you want to draw multiple independant geodesic lines within one Geodesic object you have to do it this way:

```
var berlin = new L.LatLng(52.5, 13.35);
var losangeles = new L.LatLng(33.82, -118.38);
var capetown = new L.LatLng(-33.91, 18.41);
var sydney = new L.LatLng(-33.91, 151.08);

Geodesic.setLatLngs([[berlin, losangeles], [capetown, sydney]]);
```